# How can I prevent System.Version from removing leading zeroes?

Tags: c#

```
var versionNo = new System.Version("2.01");
```

I am getting the value `versionNo` = `2.1`, but I want it as `2.01`.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: What is the difference between 01 and 1?

Comment: _"I am getting the value…"_: Could you please be more precise? Please show the code that transforms `versionNo` into the string `"2.1"`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's how [`system.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) works - it stores the components of the version as separate integers, so there's no distinction between `2.01` and `2.1`.  If you *need* to display it that way you could format it as:

```
Version versionNo = new Version("2.01");
string s = string.Format("{0}.{1:00}",versionNo.Major, versionNo.Minor);
```

For convenience you could also create an extension method:

```
public static string MyFormat(this Version ver)
{
    return string.Format("{0}.{1:00}",ver.Major, ver.Minor);
}
```

That way you can still customize the *display* while retaining the comparability of the `Version` class.

Answer (score 7):

Each component of System.Version is an int, so it doesn't pad the 0. You could have a major, minor, and build:

```
Version versionNo = new Version("2.0.1");
```

which results in

```
Version = 2.0.1
```

but generally, 01 and 1 are equivalent. If you want to specifically have the any component of the Version 0 padded, I suggest you <s>override the ToString method of version or</s> create an extension method (as mentioned by D Stanley), or use a different type.

Comment: You: _I suggest you override the ToString method of version, [...]_ Note, however, that `System.Version` is a `sealed` class. So you can't technically `override` since you can't derive from the class. But you can write a class that wraps `System.Version`, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If your version is `2.01`, that means your `MinorVersion` is `01`.

To output that, you'd have to [**pad**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx) the `MinorVersion`, by doing:

```
string version = version.Major.ToString() + version.Minor.ToString("D2");
```